# func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) not fired on custom NSTextfield

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstextfield, appkit, first-responder

I have a subclass of NSTextfield, within which I have overridden "mouseDown" function to perform some activity. The "mouseDown" of the NSTextField subclass is being executed only when the textfield is not the firstResponder. If the textfield is already firstResponder(with blue border color) mouseDown is not being executed at all. Is there a way to make sure that the mouseDown is always triggered irrespective of whether the control is the firstResponder or not.

Comment: Do you want to do something while the user is selecting the text?

Comment: I have to show a pop over when user clicks inside the textfield irrespective of the contents of the textfield.

Comment: So the user wants to move the insertion point or select some text and this triggers a popover? Read about [the field editor](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextFieldsAndViews/TextFieldsAndViews.html).